# PHP - Enter query into MySQL without quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with trying to enter data in MySQL without it being in quotes.

Below is a screenshot of how it appears in MySQL

[image: DB ENTRY]

Below is the INSERT INTO code which puts it into the database, I need it to be entered into MySQL without quotes which is proving challenging...

```
    <?php include('db_connect.inc');?>

<?php
$result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dog_park.reviews (review_text, username, date, rating, item) VALUES (:review, :id, :date, :rating, :keyword)");
$result->bindParam(':review', $value1);
$result->bindParam(':id', $value2);
$result->bindParam(':date', $value3);
$result->bindParam(':rating', $value4);
$result->bindParam(':keyword', $value5);


$value1 = $_POST['review'];
$value2 = $_SESSION['id'];
$value3 = $date = date("Y-m-d");
$value4 = $_POST['rating'];
$value5 = $_SESSION['KEYWORD'];
$result->execute();
echo "Review entry Successful, you will now be redirected to the home page";

header( "refresh:10; url=index.php" );
?>
```

Maybe something to do with $_SESSION ??

Comment: nothing wrong with your code. How is your form? Please provide a dump of the request. the problem lies there..

Comment: Something out of order here. you should define the `$valueN` variables before binding the parameters. Also add in your code `var_dump($_POST)` and see what is comming

Comment: Start at the form and follow the processing. Nothing here would be adding the quotes to the DB. Maybe when you store the session value you concat quotes?

Comment: Nothing Wrong??? Everything seems wrong to me.

Comment: @JorgeCampos results of var_dump     



**array(2) { ["review"]=> string(21) "I am leaving a review" ["rating"]=> string(1) "3" }**

Comment: @SugatoSengupta   Dump of form which goes to code posted above   


http://pastebin.com/VWLRyQmQ

Comment: @anwerjunaid eye doctor is your friend :D Jokes apart, I see nothing that can cause the extra single quotes.. Script coding style is out of the scope of this question, and I am not gonna comment on that.

Comment: @anwerjunaid what specifically seems wrong to you? Don't `var_dump($_POST)`, the data is coming from `$_SESSION`.

Comment: The order of variable assignments seems wrong, you are using **$value1**  where it is not initialized. Either code is incomplete or something. Could not out my finger on. but it just does not seem correct.

Comment: @anwerjunaid Yea, I prefer assigning first but the manual does have it defined, then assigned. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @chris85 What in the name of evil is that? PHP is still the mysterious language ever.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the post variable. Try dumping the session variable `var_dump($_SESSION)` and see what it returns.

Comment: @anwerjunaid I think we are behind on that matter. Nowadays it seems to store the variable reference. Still it is ugly as hell.

Comment: @anwerjunaid, PHP creates a variable when it first sees something that looks like a `variable create` statement. It doesn't assign it a value yet, just marks it being available as a variable. But PHP is a dynamically typed language. Later it gets set to something useful. All can, and will be resolved, when it needs to evaluate it. All the dynamic languages work this way.

Comment: @RyanVincent i am gonna use this thing alot. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  var_dump($_SESSION)       **http://pastebin.com/zjPxY40v**

Comment: Yes, there's your issue, `string(31) "'TRAMWAY ST DOG OFF LEASH AREA'" ` see the single quotes? Where are you assigning that session value?

Comment: @chris85 said, your problem is located on the file you add the values into the SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps trimming out the extraneous Quotes on both sides of each of the Posted values could do the trick for you like so:

```
    <?php
        include('db_connect.inc');
        $result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dog_park.reviews (review_text, username, date, rating, item) VALUES (:review, :id, :date, :rating, :keyword)");

        $date   = date("Y-m-d");
        $value1 = trim($_POST['review'],        "'\"");
        $value2 = trim($_SESSION['id'],         "'\"");
        $value3 = trim($date,                   "'\"");
        $value4 = trim($_POST['rating'],        "'\"");
        $value5 = trim($_SESSION['KEYWORD'],    "'\"");

        $result->bindParam(':review',   $value1);
        $result->bindParam(':id',       $value2);
        $result->bindParam(':date',     $value3);
        $result->bindParam(':rating',   $value4);
        $result->bindParam(':keyword',  $value5);

        $result->execute();
        echo "Review entry Successful, you will now be redirected to the home page";

        header( "refresh:10; url=index.php" );
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't just add band-aids, the problem should be found and fixed.

Comment: That's a bad solution IMHO. Finding the root cause of the problem will be better.

Comment: @chris85      Whatever the root cause, trimming out extraneous Quotes neither adds nor removes a thing from the Program... and ***sometimes Band-Aids could mean the difference between doing it and not doing it at all...*** but **Yes, finding the root cause should be of primary importance...** ;-)

Comment: How do you know other quotes are extraneous? What if the OP wants the string to start with a quote at some point? Band-Aids == Yuck.

Comment: @Sugato Sengupta    ***That was not meant to be a solution.*** That was more **like a clutch to a man with a broken knee.... He still can't walk but then, he can move from his room to the toilet...** get the idea?

Comment: @Chris85       Unless I can't read English, that's exactly what the OP doesn't want...  ***Now, that's what you have conjectured and want...*** fortunately, You are not the OP neither am I... and hey! ***Yuck is the beginning of a journey towards Yeah*** and you of all people should know that unless you started coding the same day you were born...

Comment: @SugatoSengupta    But neg-voting me is perfectly acceptable, isn't it? ***Your right to think and act as you wish cannot be taken by nothing in the cosmos.*** And even if you did, it is far more rewarding than you realized and thus confirms once again an age-old Truth: https://imgur.com/a/HeQc5  And for that reason I will upvote you immediately and add 2 new words to this comment: **THANK YOU!!!**

Comment: Let me reset the neg effect for ya ;)

Comment: The issue is the code appends a single quote to the start and end of the string. If the string should start with a single quote the erroneous single quotes will still supersede those. This answer will remove the erroneous and the correct one(s).

Comment: @Chris85   Did You read the Book **THE PRINCE** from **Niccolo Machiavelli?** There's a Quote I love from that Book: ***... The END justifies the MEANS...***. And here again we see it in action: ***After all analysis and diving deep into the Root-Cause; in the END, the OP chose the way of your Band-Aids: YUCK!!!*** I personally learnt one thing here and that is: ***Yuck Truly is the beginning of a journey towards Yeah!!!*** The Rest, I'd leave to you... but one thing still won't change: ***me is a band-aid, yuck fan...*** so long as it acts as **a clutch to my broken knee....**

Comment: OP doesn't know what he/she is doing, which also is why they have 3-5 questions on the same topic. I read `the little prince`, different books?

Comment: @chris85      No: that'll be all, Mr. Chris... But ***how can one describe an Orange if he (himself) has not tasted one?*** ***How can one know that the OP doesn't know what he is doing if He himself doesn't know what*** **"NOT KNOWING WHAT ONE IS DOING EXACTLY IS"?** But, sure: All Non-Yuck Geeks all know exactly what they are doing too.... **HAVE A NICE DAY, MR. CHRIS...**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stripslashes( string $str )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to un-quote quoted strings.

But in your case you need to **Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement** so you use : [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, , ', " and \x1a.

For example :

```
<?php
// We have not connected to MySQL

$lastname  = "O'Reilly";
$_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM actors WHERE last_name = '$_lastname'";

var_dump($_lastname);
var_dump($query);
?>
```

Comment: No, 1. that function `Returns a string with backslashes stripped off.`. 2. The problem should be solved, not a hack fix.

Comment: @chris85 This is just a straight answer to the question asked. How to strip of quotes. But now that I read the question again, I think the OP has to use `mysql_real_escape_string `

Comment: Nope, that is incorrect. Prepared statements are correct and don't add quotes to the actual value. The issue is elsewhere, this answer is not the answer.

Comment: @Ani Menon     ***The world is full of People who know so much yet understand so little...*** Even the Blind man can read the OP's Question. But someone knows so much to inform you that you are a hack-fixer. But then, we should all be thankful that knowledge & intelligence doesn't equate to Discernment and Clarity. ***Sometimes, ignoring those people whose Egos are huge enough to cut down the London Bridge is far better than responding to them which even fuels their ego the more....*** You did your part... now let the OP decide.... ;-)

Comment: Variable assignment, `$_SESSION['KEYWORD']`.

Comment: @Poiz Yeah, I put up what I thought was right. Chris thinks its not right. Well I would like to know why the -1?

Comment: This answer is dangerous and wrong. Prepared statements should be used, they don't add single quotes. Escaping is still open to SQL injections. Look at the OPs last comment.

Comment: @AniMenon Not really necessary... ***Remembering that in a Virtual World, everything is possible should put you at ease...*** Your vote is now balanced...

Comment: @chris85 just read the comment, looks like the OP is giving a string with quotes as input to session variable, so he has to remove the first & last char of the string.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions and `stripslashes` aren't the answer. You use `PDO` or `mysqli` because `mysql_` has been removed/deprecated. `stripslashes` does what the name implies, removes escaping slashes. Not going to enter the escaping injection conversation, there are full threads on that topic (OPs insertion code is fine as is).